# How to run "flutter test" on every run in Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, testing

I'd like to execute the "flutter test" command every time I click the "run button". How can I achieve this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

check this article :- https://medium.com/flutter-community/hot-reload-for-flutter-integration-tests-e0478b63bd54

If you're using VS Code, you can add a configuration in launch.json to run the test. Set the 'program' property to the path of the integration test.

```
 {
    "name": "Integration Test: Run Test",
    "program": "project_root/integration_test/foo_test.dart",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "dart"
},
```

You can also restart the program via VS Code and the test will run again.

Comment: I am using Android Studio